# Serializing a struct whose definition is not known

Tags: c++, serialization, struct, deserialization, geos

I am using geos library in my software as the geometry engine. I am currently using its capi(as that is the recommended api).

Now the problem is I would like to serialize and deserialize the struct GEOSGeometry. The library itself is in c++ and the capi is a wrapper around it. So the struct definition is not available per say. What are my options?

This is what the capi mentions

```
/* When we're included by geos_c.cpp, those are #defined to the original
* JTS definitions via preprocessor. We don't touch them to allow the
* compiler to cross-check the declarations. However, for all "normal"
* C-API users, we need to define them as "opaque" struct pointers, as
* those clients don't have access to the original C++ headers, by design.
*/
#ifndef GEOSGeometry
typedef struct GEOSGeom_t GEOSGeometry;
```

And this is how it is wrapped

```
// Some extra magic to make type declarations in geos_c.h work - 
// for cross-checking of types in header.
#define GEOSGeometry geos::geom::Geometry
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look in namespace geos in namespace geom.  Alternatively serialize functionally, via whatever interface.  The comments say it is exposed to cpp users, find it.

Comment: Its a class. Looks like I will have to use the c++ api afterall.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you really can't access `struct`'s definition in a source file, I'd try to inspect it with C++11 `type_traits` classes, e.g. `is_pod`, `is_trivial`, `is_standard_layout`, ...

This way, you can get an idea of what are you dealing with. If you see that the `struct` is quite simple, you can "hope" that it stores all data inside itself, i.e. not points to other memory areas. Sadly, as far as I know, there is no way to find out if a class has got a member pointer.

Eventually, all you can do is trying to serialize it brutally writing to your output `sizeof(GEOSGeometry)` bytes (`char`s). Then read it back and... good luck!

Comment: Thanks. The structure is not a struct at all. It turns out to be a class. sizeof(GEOSGeometry) cannot be detrmined by the compiler since the definition is incomplete for it. I think I will have to use the c++ api and serialize the class. Unfortunately!